# Communication between Class and Main Activity Android

Tags: android, class, broadcastreceiver, communication, main-activity

I am new in Android so I hope you can excuse my ignorance

I made an activity to control some bluetooth devices with my telephone, now that everything is working I would like to generate a new class from this activity, a class to take care of all bluetooth communication.

I have some questions:

First: In my activty I employed one broadcast receiver to listen to some actions of the Bluetooth Adapter like STATE_ON, BOND_BONDED... Using this actions I update my views, I call some methods and so on.

So, it is possible to keep listening to this broadcast receiver **inside** my class and then send the changes to my main activity to update the views and so on?

Second:  I really need to send information from my bluetooth class to my main activity, information that I read from my devices, information from the broadcast receiver... so, which is the best way to pass information between a class and the main activity?

Well, thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/4011057/534471

Answer (score 0):

The onReceive() method of your BroadcastReceiver is called from the main thread:
"This method is always called within the main thread of its process" ([http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29)).

That means you can update your ui from the onReceive() method. All you need to do is use a local class like so:

```
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // update the ui
    }
};
```

Register this receiver programmatically (instead of defining it in the manifest) and you're good to go:

```
Context.registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter)
```

Comment: So I can't listen to the BroadcastReceiver I'm using to get the different states of the bluetooth adapter inside my bluetooth class?

Comment: You can but then you'll have to send a broadcast from your receiver in your bluetooth class to above BroadcastReceiver. You can use the LocalBroadcastManager to send the broadcast (more efficient and more secure).