# Updating list activity using broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, listactivity

I've recently started android development and wanted to do something as an experiment.
I have a list of phone numbers, when I click one of them it shows ShowPhoneActivity with a List of sms from the number I clicked in main activity

This is the code from onCreate method in ShowPhoneActivity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //PhoneDao is a class that handle Phone details
        dao = new PhoneDAO(this);
        //this receives the data of the main activity
        Bundle showData = getIntent().getExtras();
        phoneNumber = showData.getString("phone_number");
        phoneID = showData.getInt("phone_id");

        //Query for the sms
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, "address = \"" + phoneNumber + "\"", null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        // Read the sms data and store it in the list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                SMSData sms = new SMSData();
                sms.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
                sms.setNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
                smsList.add(sms);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }

        // Set smsList in the ListAdapter
        setListAdapter(new ListSMSAdapter(this, smsList));

    }
```

This code may be placed somewhere else (I'm not sure where). So everything works fine, but know I want to **update** the list whenever I get a new SMS. So in order to do that I found that I have to create a BroadcastReceiver and I've done this.

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    /*Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);

                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: " + senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();*/

                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

The toast works fine, but I want to update the List in my activity, I've found the following alternatives:

- **Update the adapter** (as far as I search I haven't properly set an adapter here) **with
  notifyDatasetChanged**, but I'm not sure where to put that method.
- In ShowPhoneActivity, **create onPause and onResume methods with a BroadcastReceiver object**, inside onPause write the code to fill the list. I'm not sure if I have to
  paste the same code inside onCreate.

As the title of my question says, I need help with that or some tutorials about this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275042/android-best-practice-on-updating-the-ui-from-broadcastreceiver-to-a-certain-act the first answer will provide all you need to do following the notifyDatasetChanged alternative

Comment: @GhostDerfel The problem is that my activity extends ListActivity, so I can't call notifyDataSetChanged, setListAdapter(new ListSMSAdapter(this, smsList));.
Besides that I made the broadcastrecieve inside my activity works :)

Answer (score 0):

first you have to register your broadcast receiver in you main activity

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                "com.android.mymessage");
        registerReceiver(messageReceiver, intentFilter);
```

an then implement broadcast receiver

```
 private BroadcastReceiver messageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getExtras().getString("message") != null) {
                if (intent.getExtras().getString("message").equals("abc")) {
                    Intent nextscreen = new Intent(SecondVerification.this, ThirdVerification.class);
                    startActivity(nextscreen);
                }
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver);
    }
```

Now send changed data to your receiver from where changes occurs

```
Intent verifyIntent=new Intent("com.android.mymessage");
                        verifyIntent.putExtra("message",message);
                        context.sendBroadcast(verifyIntent);
```