# Android ethernet connected imageView on Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I depending on the current network status , 
Change image.

WI-FI , ethernet, unable network.

I want implement Asynctask.
but I don't know how can I implement.

this code 
When ethernet connected.

thanks.

```
public class EthernetImage extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, ImageView> {

    ImageView ethernet;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ethernet = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.EthernetConnected);
    }

    @Override
    protected ImageView doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        int m_iNetworkType = (activeNetwork == null) ? -1 : activeNetwork.getType();
        if (m_iNetworkType == cm.TYPE_WIFI) {
            ethernet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if (m_iNetworkType == cm.TYPE_ETHERNET) {
            ethernet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            ethernet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return ethernet;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ImageView result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null);
        ethernet.setImageResource(R.drawable.ethernetimage);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to change image in your imageView according to if else conditions.

Comment: How can I condition ?

Comment: change return type of `AsyncTask` to boolean or anything else than `ImageVIew`. and check same condition in `onPostExecute` method and change image accordingly..

Comment: but annoying , please give me  example code , sorry :);

Answer (score 0):

Change defination of `AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, ImageView>` to `AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>` and change methods accordingly

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    if (m_iNetworkType == cm.TYPE_WIFI) {
        return "wifi";
    } else if (m_iNetworkType == cm.TYPE_ETHERNET) {
        return "ethernet";
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and check condition in

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (result != null) {
        if("ethernet".equals(result)) {
            ethernet.setImageResource(R.drawable.ethernetimage);
        } else if("wifi".equals(result)) {
            ethernet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        ethernet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: public class EthernetImage extends AsyncTask<ImageView,Void,String>  -> class 'EthernetImage ' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'doInBackground(params) in 'asynctask' error

Comment: Change solution.check it out.

Comment: I try AsyncTask<ImageView,Void,String>   to <Void,Void,String>

Comment: hide imageView in else condition `ethernet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: add question. recently, new EthernetImage().execute() call on onresume()      I want without changing the screen, when the network changes, change the image. I think create receiver class. is it right?

Comment: Yes, you have to create `BroadcastReceiver` to check if network state changed and is online, and then change image in image view.

Comment: how use  findViewById in receiver class

Comment: read the answer. It'll help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215878/how-to-update-the-ui-of-activity-from-broadcastreceiver

Comment: new IntentFilter("YourIntentAction") comment. I don't know ("YourIntentAction") what I should IntentAction write?

Comment: check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app

Comment: ohhhhhh... very hard :(;;

Comment: what typing this command? 

I WI-FI receiver         registerReceiver(rssiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION));

but I don't know    ethernet receiver , unable network receiver 
what typing 'here type'?