# Service and Main activity communication

Tags: android, service, mapfragment

I am having an activity, which populates a frame layout and a **MapFragment** on top of it. The map markers should be updated every few minutes, so I thought I may use a **Service** to generate http requests.

The question is, how can this service (which is not implemented yet) can communicate or update my MapFragment's UI and some of Main Activity's UI ?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your activity/fragment from service by registering a broadcast receiver.

[**Look Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215878/how-to-update-the-ui-of-activity-from-broadcastreceiver)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, 
it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here 
and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

You can receive updates for your activity from service, please see this counter example to get help in doing it.

**CounterUpdates.java**

```
package yourPackage;

public class CounterUpdates {
    private static CounterUpdates mInstance;
    private ICounterUpdates mListener;

    private CounterUpdates() {}

    public static CounterUpdates getInstance() {
        if(mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new CounterUpdates();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void setListener(ICounterUpdates listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void onCountUpdate(int count) {
        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.onCountUpdate(count);
        }
    }


    // Definition of location updates interface
    public interface ICounterUpdates {
        public void onCountUpdate(int count);
    }
}
```

**CounterService.java**

```
package yourPackage;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class CounterService extends Service {

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private int mCount = 0;
    private static final int INTERVAL = 500;
    private Runnable mRunnableCounter = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            deliverResults(++mCount);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL);
        }
    };


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        startCounterThread();
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    private void startCounterThread() {
        mCount = 0;
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnableCounter, INTERVAL);
    }

    private void stopCounterThread() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnableCounter);
    }



    public static void deliverResults(int count) {
        CounterUpdates.getInstance().onCountUpdate(count);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopCounterThread();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** (Register your service)

```
<service android:name="yourPackage.CounterService" />
```

**To Start Service** Use this code:

```
startService(new Intent(this, CounterService.class));
```

**YourActivity.java**

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements CounterUpdates.ICounterUpdates {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        CounterUpdates.getInstance().setListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCountUpdate(int count) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Count: " + count);
    }

}
```

I hope it will work, best of luck :)