# Activity and thread communications

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an activity in which i trigger a thread, That thread is updating the ui elements on that same activity. When activity goes background, the thread is still running, but when i resume activity, the thread is running but not updating UI. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

Comment: the views are destroyed when you leave the app and they are recreated again when you come back to the app. They are not the same. To avoid this use livedata with viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Broadcast Receiver` to update the the UI from different Thread.
Register the Broadcast receiver inside `onResume()` and Update the UI inside `onreceive()` of `Broadcast Receiver`.

Check below link for referrence.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216606/4657385